# Limits on PostgreSQL schema changes inside transactions?

Tags: postgresql, transactions, schema, ddl

My database background is with Oracle, so I was surprised to discover that Postgres includes schema changes in transactions - if you begin one, create a table and then rollback, the table goes away. It works for adding and removing columns as well. Obviously this is very nice.

We're about to make some changes to the way we deploy schema deltas that rely on this feature. Before we do, I'd like to find out how far the transactional guarantee extends, but I can't find any information on it in the documentation. I assume I'm just using the wrong search terms - my searches just go to big lists of commands which include the words 'transaction', 'create' and 'table'.

Can anyone give me some pointers to docs or discussions about transactional schema changes in Postgres? (We're using 8.2.13, although we'll be upgrading in the not too distant future.) Or just some details about statement that won't be included in the transaction?

Comment: Yes - that feature is extremely useful for writing upgrade scripts.

Comment: Gah - those are both good answers. In the end the deciding factor was that the grep is hopefully a more exhaustive list. (Although it doesn't mention REINDEX.) Thanks.

Comment: depesz has made massive contributions to the postgresql community, such as through his blog. If you ask me - he deserves a high reputation score!

Comment: SQL Server can also rollback DDL and data changes from within the same transaction.  But alloyingly each DDL statement must come first in a batch (separated by GO).  The DDL is not properly isolated from other transactions, like in postgres, but the important thing is the complete rollback in case of error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to quick grep on docs, these commands cannot be executed in transactions:

- cluster
- commit prepared
- create database
- create tablespace
- discard
- drop database
- drop tablespace
- rollback prepared
- vacuum

Comment: sure: grep 'cannot be executed inside a transaction' sql-*html

Comment: Thanks. The reindex docs have more whitespace between exactly those words.

Comment: CLUSTER can run inside a transaction block as long as you specify which tables to CLUSTER.

Answer (score 9):

- `nextval` and `setval` operations on sequences are never rolled back.
- `REINDEX DATABASE`
- `REINDEX SYSTEM`

There's an [article about transactional DDL on the PostgreSQL Wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Transactional_DDL_in_PostgreSQL:_A_Competitive_Analysis)

Answer (score 4):

As of version 9.1 of PosgreSQL, it appears that schema create statements are indeed transactional.

```
select * from pg_namespace where nspname = 'foo';
 nspname | nspowner | nspacl 
---------+----------+--------
(0 rows)

begin;
create schema foo;
rollback;

select * from pg_namespace where nspname = 'foo';
 nspname | nspowner | nspacl 
---------+----------+--------
(0 rows)

begin;
create schema foo;
commit;

select * from pg_namespace where nspname = 'foo';
 nspname | nspowner | nspacl 
---------+----------+--------
 foo     |       10 | NULL
(1 row)
```

Comment: This is already the case for many years, nothing new and not related to version 9.1

Comment: Tested in PostgreSQL 8.4 (version from RHEL6). And it works! :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Two sessions concurrently running "CREATE TABLE" is a little racy:

http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Errors-on-CREATE-TABLE-IF-NOT-EXISTS-td5659080.html

> CREATE TABLE does a preliminary check to see whether a name conflict
>   exists.  If so, it either errors out (normally) or exits with a notice
>   (in the IF NOT EXISTS case).  But there's a race condition: a
>   conflicting transaction can create the table after we make that check
>   and before we create it ourselves.

Both the linked thread initiator and I hit this in automated testing environments,
so it's not much more than an annoyance there.  (I doubt it would effect your schema migrations, but it can be seen as a limit on ddl changes)

```
perl -MDBI -E 'fork; fork; $d=DBI->connect("dbi:Pg:dbname=$ENV{USER}");' \
 $d->do("CREATE TABLE a (b int)")'
DBD::Pg::db do failed: ERROR:
   duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pg_type_typname_nsp_index"
DETAIL:  Key (typname, typnamespace)=(a, 2200) already exists. at -e line 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

From the manual, [section 13.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc-caveats.html) (Currency Control: Caveats):

> Some DDL commands, currently only TRUNCATE and the table-rewriting
>   forms of ALTER TABLE, are not MVCC-safe. This means that after the
>   truncation or rewrite commits, the table will appear empty to
>   concurrent transactions, if they are using a snapshot taken before the
>   DDL command committed. This will only be an issue for a transaction
>   that did not access the table in question before the DDL command
>   started […]

Regarding table rewriting the [ALTER TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) section mentions

> Adding a column with a DEFAULT clause or changing the type of an
>   existing column will require the entire table […] to be
>   rewritten. As an exception when changing the type of an existing
>   column, if the USING clause does not change the column contents and
>   the old type is either binary coercible to the new type or an
>   unconstrained domain over the new type, a table rewrite is not needed […] Adding
>   or removing a system oid column also requires rewriting the entire
>   table.