# Is it possible to wrap DDL changes in a transaction in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, ddl

I know that in MySQL ddl statements such as alter table/create table/etc cause an implicit transaction commit.

As we are moving to PostgreSQL is it possible to wrap multiple DDL statments in a transaction?

This would make migration scripts a lot more robust, a failed DDL change would cause everything to rollback.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

DDL statements are covered by transactions.  I can't find the relevant section in the official documentation, but have provided a link to the wiki which covers it.

Just remember that transactions aren't automatically opened in postgresql, you must start them with `BEGIN` or `START TRANSACTION`.

[Postgresql Wiki about Transactional DDL](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Transactional_DDL_in_PostgreSQL%3a_A_Competitive_Analysis)

Comment: I don't think there is a special chapter about transactional DDL in the manual. If I'm not mistaken you can assume every statement to be transactional **unless** stated otherwise. So the manual will only documente those that are non-transactional (e.g. `create database`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Thanks. Do you know where in the manual, does it say that DDL or dropping a database can't be within a transaction? Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51869619/does-dropping-a-database-have-to-be-done-not-in-any-transaction

Comment: @Tim: the first sentence in the [Notes section](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdatabase.html#id-1.9.3.58.7) is: "*CREATE DATABASE cannot be executed inside a transaction block*"

Answer (score 22):

Not every Postgres DDL statement can be wrapped in transaction. Statements like `DROP DATABASE` / `DROP TABLESPACE` and some other file-system-related cant rollback.

Also:

> ALTER TYPE ... ADD VALUE (the form that adds a new value to an enum
>   type) cannot be executed inside a transaction block.

Also some statements like `TRUNCATE` are 'not MVCC save'. Changes, made by that kind of statements can affect other queries, even if they are rolled back.

So - read the official manual for your version of postgres to find out if your DDL's are transaction safe.

Comment: The `TRUNCATE` issue remains true in 9.2, at least according to the documentation. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-truncate.html . Pretty much everything except DB creation/drop and `TRUNCATE` is transaction-safe though.

Comment: And what about `DROP TABLESPACE` ? According to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108749/limits-on-postgresql-schema-changes-inside-transactions?rq=1 it isn't safe (or it wasn't safe).

Comment: Important clarification.  truncate IS transaction safe, it is NOT MVCC safe.

Comment: @Craig ALTER TYPE ... ADD VALUE also cannot be executed inside transaction